# Real time notification using angularjs php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, real-time

I would like to implement a real time notification like facebook on my website using angular, php and mysql. Is there any reference links or tutorials anyone can help me out with?

Also, is there any other tools by which I can implement the same on my website?

Comment: You should have googled before asking such questions..

Comment: There's no simple answer to this. You'll want to research "long polling" or if you are feeling adventurous a library such as socket.io

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Socket.io, it will help you to implement notification , chat or any real time application.

Comment: any tutorial you can suggest using it with PHP? Also, is there any support issues on browser like internet explorer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these things to make such functionalities.

1. PHP JSON Based API
2. PHP Socket Based JSON API
3. Socket IO based API

All these API can easily be parsed by AngularJS or jQuery

**For PHP, How to make an API**

```
<?php
//Set header for Javascript to recognize it as the JSON output
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
//I am using GET parameters, but POST can also be used and can make amazing APIs
switch($_GET['action']){
    case "addlike":
         //SQL Query passed to add a like as facebook
         //Set the output array to provide json Output, here's the example
         $output['status'] = 200;
         $output['message'] = 'Like Added';
    break;
    case "addcomment":
    break;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

To use above code, the URL would be:

```
http://yourserve/youfile.php/?action=addlike
```

And the Output would be

```
{
  "status":200,
  "message":"Like Added"
}
```

**How to use it in jQuery**

```
/** For Example you have like button with class="btnlike" **/
$('.btnlike').on('click',function(){
    $.get('http://yourserve/youfile.php',{action:'addlike'},function(data){
        if(data['status'] == 200){ alert('You Liked the Post'); }
    });
});
```

**How to use in AngularJS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.addlike = function(){
        $http.get('http://yourserve/youfile.php',{action:"addlike"}).success(function(data){
             if(data['status']==200){ $scope.messages = 'You liked the post'; }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: this was really helpful Marmik, can you please help me out with implementing this on a thing like showing notification after a cron job execution. for eg, consider a cron job executing every 5 minutes and update some data to mysql table. I have to show a real time notification after that. How can I acheive this with angular? since I have no event like a button click, how can I invoke angular code??

Comment: Dear Akhil, you can do this by simple javascript function called setinterval, it will allow you to fire a code or function in intervals (time you set: maybe a second or so). please check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: any performance issues with this? How about a high traffic website? Any issues performing an AJAX request every second?

Comment: It may have but, if you use core PHP, you will get good results, if you use any framework it can slow down the speed, please check this link: https://systemsarchitectdotnet.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/php-benchmark.png

Comment: how many users initially your planning to serve? I will help you to complete your project..provide me some more details of functionalities

Comment: It is kind of a social network and current case is  like you have commented on my photo and I have to get the notification

Comment: If possible, I suggest you to use Codeigniter or Laravel or Phalcon etc...for better performance, if you plan for App in future you will require same API for web to be used in App so Codeigniter is very easy MVC framework

Comment: Am afraid I cannot change the framework. Is there any way to implement this zf2 and node js or something like @Meesam mentioned. But am really confused with implementing it on a shared server as I will be initially running on it.

Comment: No worries you can go with zf2, but once your project is having huge crowd you can switch to nodejs, it gives clustering facility

Comment: so you suggest socket.io with nodejs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112476/discussion-between-akhil-and-marmik-bhatt).